# How to change indirect to vlookup to use in arrayformula iteration

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, vlookup, array-formulas

I have the following:

```
=indirect("'Form Responses 1'!A"&G2)
```

Where column A has timestamps and column G in this sheet has row numbers. I need to iterate that using arrayformula like this:

```
=ArrayFormula(indirect("'Form Responses 1'!A"&G2:G))
```

However, that didn't work. I found out that indirect doesn't work within Arrayformula, and that I should use vlookup instead, but I don't know how to get it to work or how to reference rows in vlookup.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with BYROW to iterate "row by row":

```
=BYROW(G2:G,LAMBDA(each,IF(each="","",Indirect("'Form Responses 1'!A"&each))))
```